# Helm lint error but everything looks ok to me

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm getting this error when linting my helm project

```
$ helm lint --debug                                
==> Linting .
[INFO] Chart.yaml: icon is recommended
[ERROR] templates/: render error in "myProject/templates/configmap.yaml": template: myProject/templates/configmap.yaml:26:27: executing "myProject/templates/configmap.yaml" at <.Values.fileServiceH...>: can't evaluate field fileHost in type interface {}

Error: 1 chart(s) linted, 1 chart(s) failed
```

This is my `configmap.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myProject-configmap

data:
  tkn.yaml: |
    iss: "{{ .Values.iss }}"
    aud: "{{ .Values.aud }}"
  db.yaml: |
    database: "{{ .Values.database }}"
    user: "{{ .Values.user }}"
    host: "{{ .Values.host }}"
    dialect: "{{ .Values.dialect }}"
    pool:
      min: "{{ .Values.pool.min }}"
      max: "{{ .Values.pool.max }}"
      acquire: "{{ .Values.pool.acquire }}"
      idle: "{{ .Values.pool.idle }}"
  fileservice.yaml: |
    fileServiceHost:
      fileHost: "{{ .Values.fileServiceHost.fileHost }}"
  notificationservice.yaml: |
    notificationServiceHost:
      notificationHost: "{{ .Values.notificationservice.notificationHost }}"
  organizationservice.yaml: |
    organizationServiceHost:
      organizationHost: "{{ .Values.organizationservice.organizationHost }}"
  organizations.yaml: |
    organizations: {{ .Values.organizations | toJson | indent 4 }}
  epic.yaml: |
    redirectUri: "{{ .Values.redirectUri }}"
```

This is my `/vars/dev/fileservice.yaml` file

```
fileServiceHost:
  fileHost: 'https://example.com'
```

What is wrong that i'm getting this lint error?

Comment: You've said what your fileservice.yaml file contains but what is in your values.yaml? The error suggests you don't have a value for fileHost in the values.yaml in the chart. If you think you do then double-check its indentation and syntax.

Comment: Do i have to have the same yaml structure in `values.yaml` as what i'm overriding with in my `/vars/` files?

Answer (score 1):

You want to either use .Files.Get to load the yaml files or take the yaml content that you have in the yaml files and capture it in the values.yaml so that you can insert it directly in your configmap with toYaml.

If the values are just static and you don't need the user to override them then .Files.Get is better for you. If you want to be able to override the content in the yaml files easily at install time then just represent them in the values.yaml file.